# Subrings of formal series rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Let $k$ be a field and $A = k[[x_1, \dots, x_n ]]$ be the ring of formal series in $n$ variables. Consider $g_1, \dots, g_m \in A$ such that $g_1(0) = \cdots = g_m(0) = 0$. For every $f \in k[[t_1, \dots, t_m]]$ we can consider the formal series $f(g_1, \dots, g_m) \in A$ because the $g_i$'s have no constant term. Now consider the subring $B$ of $A$ made up of series of the form $f(g_1, \dots, g_m)$ as $f$ varies in $k[[t_1, \dots,t_m]]$. It is clear that $B$ is a noetherian local domain with $\dim B \leq m$.

(1) What are the main properties of the ring extension $B \subseteq A$? When is $A$ flat over $B$?

(2) After reading Problem 3 at page 115 of Milnor's *Singular points of complex hypersurfaces*, I have made the following conjecture that is an algebraization of the book's problem.

**Conjecture.** *If $m = n$ and $\sqrt{A g_1 + \cdots + A g_n } = A x_1 + \cdots + A x_n$, then $A$ is a finite free $B$-module of rank $\mu$ and $\dim_k A/(g_1, \dots, g_n) = \mu$.*

May someone prove or disprove this conjecture or tell me a good reference for complete noetherian rings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak m$ be the maximal ideal of $A$ and $\mathfrak n$ the maximal ideal of $B$.  Let $\phi:B \to A$ be the given map.  Your hypothesis is that 
$rad(A\phi(n)) = \mathfrak m,$ i.e. that $A/A\phi(\mathfrak n)$ is an Artin ring, 
i.e. that the fibre of the map Spec $A \to $ Spec $B$ over the closed point of the target is zero-dimensional.

This implies that the image of $B \to A$ must have dimension equal to $n$ (which is the image of the domain $B$), thus that this map is an injection.  The so-called "Miracle flatness theorem" (Theorem 23.1 of Matsumura's CRT) shows
that $\phi$ is necessarily flat.  Combined with the finite fibre assumption, this should then also imply that $A$ is actually *finite* flat, hence finite free,
over $B$.

Comment: Dear Matt, shouldn't the map $\phi$ in your first line go from $B$ to $A$?

Comment: @Georges: Dear Georges, Thanks!  Best wishes,